# Is there a hook for user activation (after they click the email confirm)?

Tags: hooks

Is there a hook for user activation (after they click the email confirm)? I am creating a plugin to automatically add them to my email software, but I want them to have to confirm their email first.

Comment: Have you searched [here](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks) before asking?

Answer (score 1):

[wpmu_welcome_user_notification](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpmu_welcome_user_notification) is a filter, but you can execute your action there, too.

Take care not to turn off notification mails accidentally; see [the source](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wpmu_welcome_user_notification?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/ms-functions.php).

Comment: Will this wpmu_ filter work on a regular site or is it just for multisites?

Comment: Codex doesn't say explicitly. I think I read somewhere that the multisite business has been merged into the standard version, so just have a try. Note, though, that `wpmu` probably stands for "Wordpress Multi User", not multi site.

Answer (score 1):

You want wpmu_activate_user, at least if you're on multi-site.

```
my_function($user_id, $password, $meta)   {
    // do stuff
}
add_action('wpmu_activate_user','my_function');
```

Comment: +1, but beware that this action will only fire for a "user" in even multi-site setup. If the user has requested a blog, it'll not fire on user activation.